# api upload multipartform-data

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, multipartform-data, rails-api

My `post` controller saves the Carrierwave `@post.picture` when running the below `postman` request.

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params) 
  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.save
       # .... all the json/html responses
    end
  end
end

def post_params   
  params.require(:post).permit(:description, :picture)
end
```

the postman params

```
POST /posts.json
X-User-Email: fg@email.com
X-User-Token: EBNbDysWKEYqURfpDkWo
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------329710892316545763789878
undefined:
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: e320b3bf-c5f3-4e40-a149-fd0323881ec0
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.6.0
Host: 192.168.1.104:3000
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
content-length: 586600
post[picture]=[object Object]post[description]=test
HTTP/1.1 201
status: 201
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Location: http://192.168.1.104:3000/posts/15
ETag: W/"540dd0914ae94bd0214825e73955bbde"
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
X-Request-Id: ad99898b-31db-46e0-8a4d-3fc82dafd1c1
X-Runtime: 128.284019
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
{"id":15,"description":"test","picture": {
    "url":"/uploads/Screenshot_from_2019-01-01_16-10-05.png","thumb":{
         "url":"/uploads/thumb_Screenshot_from_2019-01-01_16-10-05.png"
         },"card":{
         "url":"/uploads/card_Screenshot_from_2019-01-01_16-10-05.png"
         }
    },}
```

[image]

This are the rails params fetched from the server

```
{"post"=>
  {"picture"=>
     #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile
        @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20190115-10912-1rryjxd.png>,
        @original_filename="Screenshot from 2019-01-01 16-10-05.png", 
        @content_type="image/png", 
        @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"post[picture]\"; filename=\"Screenshot from 2019-01-01 16-10-05.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">,},}
```

I sumbit via AJAX the following form data

[image]

the Rails server processes the params as

```
{"post"=>{"picture"=> {
  "path"=>"file:///data/user/0/com.surfapp/cache/Camera/9bc15acd-01d2-4539-a930-f129d72c3dcf.jpg", 
  "name"=>"test.png", 
   "type"=>"image/png"
           }
     }
}
```

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/8nqssd/actiondispatchhttpuploadedfile/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I adopted the [following solution](https://ograycoding.wordpress.com/2012/07/03/api-upload-with-carrierwave) with a couple of modifications:

I create an [`Upload::Cache`](https://github.com/fabriziobertoglio1987/surfbackend/blob/master/lib/upload/cache.rb) class which inherits from ruby class `Tempfile` and an [`Upload::Image`](https://github.com/fabriziobertoglio1987/surfbackend/blob/master/lib/upload/image.rb) class which inherits from the [`Upload`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/UploadedFile.html) class.

The the callback [set_picture](https://github.com/fabriziobertoglio1987/surfbackend/blob/master/app/controllers/posts_controller.rb#L71) is triggered before [posts controller create action](https://github.com/fabriziobertoglio1987/surfbackend/blob/master/app/controllers/posts_controller.rb#L11) and adds the image to the `@post` before `saving`.

[Specs coverage](https://github.com/fabriziobertoglio1987/surfbackend/blob/master/spec/uploaders/picture_uploader_spec.rb) for this functionality